# C- Connected header files

Tags: file, header

I have multiple c files that use functions from other files. For example:

foo1.h

foo1.c

```
//functions
//functions of foo2
```

foo2.h

foo2.c

```
//functions
//functions of foo1
```

main.c

```
//functions of foo1
//functions of foo2
```

In which files do I have to #define the right header files?

Answer (score 0):

Before calling a function you should make sure that the function is declared. One good way to do so is to include header files with function declarations.

It is good practice to #include foo1.h from foo1.c to make sure that any declarations in foo1.h matches the definitions in foo1.h.

As you have ugly cross dependencies between foo1.c and foo2.c booth files will need to somehow include each other .h files. This can be done by #includes from the .c files but you can also do it by including from .h files. Including from .h files might be needed if a .h file uses some data type defined in another .h file.

Include guards is allways a good idea to put in your .h files to avoid that things get redeclared if the .h file is included more than once from some file.

Your main file should somehow include both .h files, this can be done by including both from main.c or by including only one .h file which then also includes the other .h file.